Pycharm how to double-click highlighting for markdown?
In pycharm, if I double click a token in a window that displays python code, the token gets highlighted at every place in the window.  It also gets highlighted in the gutter which makes it easy to scroll to other matches.
However, if the window displays a markdown file, highlighting of a double-clicked token does not appear in the window or in the gutter.
Is there a way to turn this feature on for markdown files too?
thanks.

Unfortunately, there are no features like this. But you can try some plugins instead.
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7793-markdown/versions/stable
